# Mongodb find() query criteria implicit AND?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the query

```
var p_other = 111;
var p_timestamp = ISODate("2015-05-08T07:00:00.000Z");
db.test.find({
    other: p_other,
    $or: [ 
        { "startTime": null },
        { "startTime": { $lte: p_timestamp }}
    ],
    $or: [ 
        { "endTime": null },
        { "endTime": { $gte: p_timestamp }}
    ]
})
```

on the following data:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "other" : 111,
    "startTime" : ISODate("2015-05-08T07:01:30.868Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "other" : 111,
    "startTime" : ISODate("2015-05-08T06:04:30.040Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2015-05-08T07:01:30.868Z")
}
```

Both docs are returned, where I would expect only the second one.
Running an `explain()` I get the following parsed query:

```
"parsedQuery" : {
    "$and" : [
        {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "endTime" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "endTime" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2015-05-08T07:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "other" : {
                "$eq" : 111
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the reason the first `$or` is ignored?
From what I know, there should be an implicit AND between the criteria expressions of a `find()`, although this is not mentioned in the doc (at least not [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)).
The only mention regarding the usage of multiple `$or` is in the [$and doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator):

> This query cannot be constructed using an implicit AND operation,
>   because it uses the $or operator more than once.

But either I don't understand it or this is not really an explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please read document of [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator) carefully. You will find following-

**The query cannot be constructed using an implicit AND operation, when it uses the `$or` operator multiple times.**

Following query will give you desired result :

```
var p_other = 111;
var p_timestamp = ISODate("2015-05-08T07:00:00.000Z");
db.collection.find({
other: p_other,
$and: [{
    $or: [{
        "startTime": null
    }, {
        "startTime": {
            $lte: p_timestamp
        }
    }]
}, {
    $or: [{
        "endTime": null
    }, {
        "endTime": {
            $gte: p_timestamp
        }
    }]
}]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I knew already how to work around this. This is not what I'm asking. I would like to know the reason why it's not working. Because it seems an exceptional case which in my opinion is not documented enough. One can always have multiple criteria expressions in a `find()`, but not (for an unknown reason) when having multiple `$or`.

Comment: This might be useful to you - http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/12/21/mongodb-query-tricks